# Ansible - Failure to Install MSI with ansible.builtin.win_package

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to install a .msi with Ansible from Ubuntu to Windows. I use this module ansible.builtin.win_package but i've got an error (it's very long) when i run the task "Install Zabbix Agent2". The other tasks work fine.

Here the tasks of playbook:

```
- name: Folder download
  ansible.windows.win_file:
    path: C:\Temp\
    state: directory
  tags: directory

- name: Download Zabbix Agent2
  ansible.windows.win_get_url:
    url: "{{ zabbix_win_download_link }}"
    dest: C:\Temp\
  tags: download

- name: Install Zabbix Agent2
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    path: C:\Temp\zabbix_agent2-6.0.27-windows-amd64-openssl.msi
    state: present      
  tags: install
```

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: servers
  roles:
    - windows
```

inventory:

```
[servers]
ip

[servers:vars]
ansible_user=Administrator
ansible_password="Password1!"
ansible_port=5986
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_scheme=https
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation=true
```

defaults:

```
---
# defaults file for windows
zabbix_agent_server: ip
hostmetadata: zabbix
zabbix_version: 6.0
zabbix_release: 6.0.27
zabbix_win_download_link: https://cdn.zabbix.com/zabbix/binaries/stable/{{ zabbix_version }}/{{ zabbix_release }}/zabbix_agent2-6.0.27-windows-amd64-openssl.msi
zabbix_win_install_dir: 'C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent 2'
```

I've tried to set arguments but the playbook freeze:

```
name: Install Zabbix Agent2
ansible.windows.win_package:
  path: C:\Temp\zabbix_agent2-6.0.27-windows-amd64-openssl.msi
  state: present
  arguments:
    - /install
tags: install
```

what am I doing wrong?

edit: https://system.tips/text/view?q=bhdepzmt (I can't add it here because I exceed the character limit)

edit 2: I resolve the problem. It is necessary to add the argument SERVER:ip.

```
name: Install Zabbix Agent2
ansible.windows.win_package:
  path: C:\Temp\zabbix_agent2-6.0.27-windows-amd64-openssl.msi
  state: present
  arguments: >-
    SERVER:IP
tags: install
```

See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/installation/install_from_packages/win_msi

Comment: "_but i've got an error (it's very long)_", and can you provide the very long error message by updating your question?